# How To Add A GitHub Repository To A Custom Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, chart.js

I am building out a custom Wordpress plugin for my site and would really like to integrate [ChartsJS](https://www.chartjs.org/) into the plugin's admin menu so I can track stats from my admin panel.

I have downloaded the zip file but am not sure how I could do this or how I would call that functionality from my plugin so that everything works properly.

Any help is great!

Comment: Have you checked [ChartJS' documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) yet? If not, that would be a good place to start. It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @cabrerahector been there, downloaded the zip like the post says, it's more a question of how do I call those files from inside of my plugin? Because obviously an `include` link wouldn't work

Comment: To load any JS file on the admin area use the [admin_enqueue_scripts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) function. Check the documentation for more details.

Comment: @cabrerahector that would be helpful if I only needed to load one file. As the post says this is a whole repository that needs to be called from the plugin to render the charts inside of the admin panel properly. Repo has been linked in the original post